# Microsoft StreamInSight - Missing interfaces in Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Adapters

Tags: .net, streaminsight

I'm trying to build the HitchHiker solution that comes as part of the Microsoft whitepaper on StreamInSight "A Hitchhiker‟s Guide to Microsoft StreamInsight Queries". However, I'm getting compile errors such as:
 "Error 1   The type or namespace name 'IDeclareAdvanceTimeProperties' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\gmd\Architecture\cep\HitchHiker\Adapters\InputFactory.cs 45  36  Adapters".
I have verified that the assembly references to Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Adapters.dll has been added to the project. 
Also, the object browser for the dll and intellisense does not show the interface in question.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Gautam

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to make sure that you are using the full .NET 4.0 Framework and not just the Client Profile? You can find this in your project properties. If you are using only the Client Profile, you'll get these kinds of error when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Visual Studio is having a "moment", try flipping the copy local flag on/off on the reference. I had a similar problem with another project and that resolved it for me.